# Blogger - Aligning whole template to right of screen?

Tags: alignment, blogger

I recently saw a site that had the blog aligned to the right hand side of the screen (so any extra space was on the left of the main column. Unfortunately, it was Wordpress and all I can seem to find when I search for aligning blog templates to the right is stuff about right aligning pictures.

I suppose could add padding (trial and error) on that side to bump it across, but that wouldn't display properly on other computers.

My sidebar is 325 wide and the main column is 625, leaving ~240 on the left.

I'm just using the Simple template as a base. I don't know that it's worth the time that it would take to do it from scratch. Or that I have the skills :. The Blogger help areas are practically abandoned.

Is this possible? Or are there any other ideas that could work across different computers/resolutions?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever element you want to align to the right , enclose it in a div and make it float right ? Wouldn't this work?

```
...
<div style="float:right">
    <div class='sidebar'>...</div>
    <div class='main-column'>...</div>
</div>
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I gave it a go but it still stayed left aligned. 

I tried just including the content in the header, and both then the content in the header and body, but no change either way :(.

Maybe it's that I'm after the whole template that causes the non-movement?

Comment: @skittle What Anoop is saying is correct . As you are using a Simple Blogger template , the CSS for it would be
    .content-outer { float:right; } 
I setup a demo blog with Simple template in it and it worked correctly , check it here http://prayagverma.blogspot.com/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Prayag.

Unfortunately, when I added float:right; } to the CSS, it did nothing to change it from the left. Had you meant like this:

.content-outer { float:right; }
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 $(content.shadow.spread) rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 $(content.shadow.spread.webkit) rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  -goog-ms-box-shadow: 0 0 $(content.shadow.spread.ie) #333333;
  box-shadow: 0 0 $(content.shadow.spread) rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);